# Modifying regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need help modifying the following regex expression:

```
/(<a[^<>]*\shref=[\"\'])([^#][^<\"\'>]+)([\"\'][^<>]*)(.*?<\/a>)/is
```

With this regex I am able to extract contents of the href attribute, for example using the string:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

it will extract the `http://www.google.com` and all the other things. I also included in the regex to ignore the href if it contains `#` character, that's because I'm only interested in relative and absolute links. However, I came across an anchor like this `<a href="/">Text</a>`. For some reason,  '/' character won't be matched, and I need to fix that. Here's the demo http://regexr.com/3bbul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add negative lookahead.

```
(<a[^<>]*\shref=[\"\'])(?!#)([^<\"\'>]+)([\"\'][^<>]*)(.*?<\/a>)
```

or

```
(<a[^<>]*\shref=([\"\']))(?!#)([^<\"\'>]+)(\2[^<>]*)(.*?<\/a>)
```

**What's wrong with your regex?**

```
([^#][^<\"\'>]+)
```

`[^#]` matches a single chracater.

`[^<\"\'>]+` matches catleast one char.

So this excepts atleast two chars to be present inside `href` but the value of href attrib in your input contain single character only. So no match.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3bbuo)

Comment: @splash58 he don't want `#` to be present at the start of href value.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use this Regex

```
/<a.*href="([^#]*)">.*<\/a>/is
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a little bit of explanation to your answer.